# Where do "redownloaded" pictures in WhatsApp come from?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, images

I deleted some WhatsApp messages from my phone, but they are still visible in a blurred way in the chat. I know that's normal, but when I clicked on them, they are redownloaded. Even messages from the beginning of the year.

I was wondering whether these messages are stored on WhatsApp servers, or does WhatsApp "reupload" these pictures from the phone of the sender if they are still there?

Answer (score 1):

From WhatsApp FAQ, [Troubleshoot blurry photos](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-blurry-photos),

> Once a photo is downloaded onto your device, it **can't be redownloaded**. You'd have to ask your contact to send it to you again.

(Emphasis supplied)

So, it's being retrieved from the sender.